# Unable to emerge SystemD on Hardened/SELinux

Tags: systemd, gentoo, selinux, grsecurity

I'm on the `hardened/linux/amd64/selinux` profile on a recent Stage 3 of Gentoo amd64.

I'm trying to install SystemD, and I see the following:

```
> emerge -aq sys-apps/
The following mask changes are necessary to proceed:
 ( see "package.unmask" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
# required by sys-apps/systemd (argument)
# /usr/portage/profiles/features/selinux/package.mask
# Jason Zaman<perfinion@gentoo.org> (27 Jun 2015)
# SystemD has no support in the SELinux policy at the moment.
# Please see: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/FAQ#Can_I_use_SELinux_with_SystemD.3F
=sys-apps/systemd-228-r1

Would you like to add these changes to your config files? [Yes/No]
```

I reply yes, and then see:

```
Autounmask changes successfully written.

!!! All ebuilds that could satisfy ">=sys-apps/dbus-1.6.8-r1:0[systemd]" have been masked.
!!! One of the following masked packages is required to complete your request:
- sys-apps/dbus-1.10.6::gentoo (masked by: package.mask)
/usr/portage/profiles/package.mask
# Mike Gilbert <floppym@gentoo.org> (06 Dec 2015)
# Masked for testing.

(dependency required by "sys-apps/systemd-228-r1::gentoo" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "sys-apps/systemd" [argument])
For more information, see the MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge man page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.
```

For reference, my /etc/portage/make.conf looks like this:

```
CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
CXXFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
USE="bindist mmx sse sse2 systemd -consolekit"
PORTDIR="/usr/portage"
DISTDIR="${PORTDIR}/distfiles"
PKGDIR="${PORTDIR}/packages"
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="~amd64"
```

If I visit the [url mentioned above](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/FAQ#Can_I_use_SELinux_with_systemd.3F), I see the following:

[image]

TL;DR: It's possible to use SystemD with SELinux, but see a bug report.

I'm trying to learn the ropes of Gentoo. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I'd just like to get SystemD installed so I can proceed with my installation.

---

EDIT: So evidently, it's asking for a version of DBUS that's still in testing, 1.10.6. However, there are DBUS packages which still satisfy its request. It is asking for `>=sys-apps/dbus-1.6.8-r1:0[systemd]` and in stable there is 1.8.16, which should satisfy the requirement. I've manually installed DBUS and added `dbus` to my USE flags, and it still won't resolve. Why is it unable to see that the DBUS requirement is satisfied?

**EDIT 2**: I've been able to get a bit further, but things seem to self conflict:

[image]